# Modernizer feature Detects

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, modernizr

I have to use modernizer to detect whether the browser supports "cssscrollbar" property, true or false. Based on that value I have to do stuff like adding plugin and CSS.

I am using something like this below, which I am not aware of:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for ( prop in Modernizr ) {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.textContent = prop + ': ' + Modernizr[ prop ];
  frag.appendChild( para );
}

document.body.appendChild( frag );
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jc45A/) which I am referring to.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: i am using 2.6.2 which havenot got the support for cssscrollbar so i want to add a test for scrollbar in to plugin....i am very new to modernizer.

Comment: So you're wondering how to test for that feature or how to integrate the test into Modernizr?

Comment: how do i test for the feature

Answer (score 0):

```
Modernizr.addTest('cssscrollbar', function() {

        // Tested Element
    var test = document.createElement('div'),

        // Fake body
        fake = false,
        root = document.body || (function () {
            fake = true;
            return document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('body'));
        }()),

        property = 'scrollbar{width:0px;}';

    // Force scrollbar
    test.id = '__sb';
    test.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    test.style.width = '40px';

    // Apply scrollbar style for all vendors
    test.innerHTML = '&shy;<style>#'+Modernizr._prefixes.join(property+' #__sb::').split('#').slice(1).join('#')+property+'</style>';

    root.appendChild(test);

    // If css scrollbar is supported, than the scrollWidth should not be impacted
    var ret = test.scrollWidth == 40;

    // Cleaning
    document.body.removeChild(test);
    if (fake) {
        document.documentElement.removeChild(root);
    }
    return ret;
});
```

if u add this then u will have cssscrollbar support for the modernizer..................

Answer (score 0):

There's the [testProp()](http://modernizr.com/docs/#testprop) function:

```
Modernizr.testProp('css-scrollbar');
```

Or you can [customize your Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) (open the "Non core detects"):